# difference in product using two different ways in python

Tags: python

I am experiencing a weird issue in finding the product of some numbers in two different ways. Example below. Can someone explain why the first method is not giving the correct answer?

Method 1:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3]]*34
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

np.prod([len(x) for x in arr])
-217042295
```

Method 2:

```
pr = 1
for x in arr: pr = pr*len(x)
pr
16677181699666569
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your numpy (I assume `np` is short for `numpy`) uses 32-bit integers.

That happens either because that is somehow the default for your computer, or because you configured numpy to use `int32` as the default `dtype` for these operations. You can manually control this by providing `np.prod` with `dtype=np.int64` to get the correct result.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = [[1,2,3]] * 34
>>> np.prod([len(x) for x in arr], dtype=np.int32)
-217042295
>>> np.prod([len(x) for x in arr], dtype=np.int64)
16677181699666569
>>>
```